# How to set up Neo4J 3.x community edition backup without stopping the database?

Tags: neo4j, database-backups

I want to set up automatic online backups of Neo4J 3.x community edition. I understand that this option is available only for the enterprise editions. But is there any way I could do it for the community edition?

Do I have to stop the database and do the dumps? What if I do the dumps on the running DB?

Is there any trick I could do to back up my data?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to stop the database to avoid corrupted data. Online backups are available in EE only.

Comment: So then community version doesn't allow any backup without interrupting the service?

Comment: Exactly that @Dmitry Paranyushkin

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen hm...

Answer (score 2):

**Neo4J Community Edition does not allow live backup**

As mentioned by @ChristopheWillemsen, that feature is available only in the Enterprise version. It is 100% impossible to do backups without bringing the database down in Community.

More information is available at the online operations manual page for backing up, as well as the notation that this is an Enterprise-only feature (note the "Enterprise Edition" tag in the chapter heading).

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup/

Answer (score 1):

You need Neo4j Enterprise Edition for that.   Neo4j Enterprise is actually open source as well, why not just use Neo4j Enterprise under the open source license. You won't get production support - then again you don't get that with community anyway.